# Please help simplifying this IF statement

Tags: arrays, if-statement, dynamic, excel-formula

I have this IF statement that is doing what I want it to do, but I would like it to have more nested statements and excel won't allow it.

- In each row I have one course mark for each student, sorted by their ID number.
- Some students have 11 lines of courses and some have 30.

I want a formula that will find the highest course mark for each student, based off of their id, but some students have 30 lines of courses before the next student's courses start so currently I can only read the first 12 lines (courses) for each student.

If anyone has a suggestion I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

> =IF(A2=D6,IF(A2=D7,IF(A2=D8,IF(A2=D9,IF(A2=D10,IF(A2=D11,IF(A2=D12,LARGE(H2:M12,1),LARGE(H2:M11,1)),LARGE(H2:M10,1)),LARGE(H2:M9,1)),LARGE(H2:M8,1)),LARGE(H2:M7,1)),LARGE(H2:M6,1)),"")

Comment: You can use a combination of MAX and INDEX to do what you want - see here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/615464-find-max-value-1-criteria-no-array.html

Comment: It will help to have a visual of your data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the students data is located at `F6:M562` and the output at `B6:C31` enter this *Formula Array* at `C7` and copy till last record at `C31`

*Enter the `FormulaArray` pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly.*

```
=LARGE(IF($F$6:$F$562<>$B7,0,$H$6:$M$562),1)
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much. One more question, if you don't mind. 

Using your spreadsheet above...
Suppose that course 03, Course 04, Course 08, Course 10 and Course 25 were all modules of one actual course. How could I get an average of those five? I would probably make a new column called Mark 7 and then just have the average show up on the same row as course 03. 

I think I could get that average included into the large statement that you provided  and I think I can exclude the data that would be counted twice but not sure I know how to get the average of those five.

Comment: On your second question, that's what I have in mind originally, but has to worked this way since you did not answer my earlier request about a visual of your data.